# List users of an artifact in a repository

Tags: maven, artifactory

I need a tool that will help to find all artifacts that reference another artifact.

When I rebuild an artifact, I need to update/rebuild all artifacts that were using the old version. But I work in a big organisation, and nobody knows really where the artifact is spread in the organisation, so nobody is ever completely sure that everybody use the latest versions.

What I need would be a tool - maybe an artifactory plugin or feature, or a maven plugin doing a lookup in the repository - that indexes all the known poms, and is able to make a listing of all artifacts that have the updated artifact in their dependencies, either directly and transitively. Thus a list of artifacts I would need to rebuild. Quite the opposite of `dependency:tree`.

Filtering that list by repository, groupId, packaging, etc. is a nice to have. But I can live without.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Artifactory Query Language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) with the REST API to do that. For example, if you want to find all builds that use "`MySuperAwesomeDependency-1.0.2`" your AQL statement would be something like:

```
//Find builds that use a dependency that is a snapshot
builds.find({"module.dependency.item.name":{"$match":"MySuperAwesomeDependency-1.0.2*"}})
```

The key in the above statement would be the `module.dependency.item.name`, which allows you to search for dependencies by name, assuming you store the dependencies in Artifactory.

Comment: Looks promising: ``curl -v -s -k --basic -K myuser:mypassword -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data 'builds.find({"module.dependency.item.name":{"$match":"my-artifact-name"}})' -f -X POST https://artifactory.mydomain.com/artifactory/api/search/aql || echo Unsuccessful``, but actually I get a 403. Will ask my admins if they can unlock this feature.